# bash: opposite of "histignore" behavior

Tags: bash, command-history

I am looking for a way to ignore every command by default, unless I specifically want to save it in history. Ideally, saving a command should be as easy as prepending it with a space.

Comment: Which OS / distribution do you use?

Comment: I was hoping the solution would be at most bash version specific, not distro-specific. If it's relevant, I use mostly RHEL 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ignore any command not starting with a space, say

```
HISTIGNORE='[^ ]*'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Everything gets ignored, space or not. Before we start looking into particulars of my environment - does this work for you or for people who upvoted?

Comment: Try HISTIGNORE='[^ ]?*'` so that the star is modifying the "any" expression.

Comment: Never mind, it was because of HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth.